# A non-trivial pathfinding

Tags: exchanges

Having the Lumens as the native currency in the system, it seems to me that the trivial pathfinding: `Asset-src -> Lumens -> Asset-dst` would be the most efficient one, from the fees perspective. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fees present a minuscule fraction of the value of trades, so I assume you are asking about paths that offer the best rates.

Offers do not need to involve XLM. There may exist offers between two custom assets that enable a more beneficial path. For example, consider the following offers:

```
1. sell 80 USD, buy 100 AUD
2. sell 100 AUD, buy 500 PANCAKE
3. sell 80 USD, buy 160 XLM
4. sell 175 XLM, buy 500 PANCAKE
```

In this contrived example, you get more `PANCAKE` for your `USD` if you traverse `USD->AUD->PANCAKE`, than if you traverse `USD->XLM->PANCAKE`.